# How to rollback gremlin transaction using gremlinpython?

Tags: transactions, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I'm new to gremlin, I'm trying to use python library gremlinpython to connect to Janus Graph
and need to know if it is possible to rollback transaction.

I've found that single traversal is equivalent to single transaction (tinkerPop docs), traversal is created after connecting to gremlin server:
`g = traversal().withRemote(...)`
and all operations with g are executed in a single transaction.

But I can't find what will happen if error occurs in any of operations.
Is it possible to rollback all operations made with g?
gremlin server allows to do smth like `g.tx().rollback()` or `g.tx().commit()` - to rollback or approve transaction, but is it possible to do this using gremlinpython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an error occurs then Gremlin Server will automatically rollback the transaction for you. If it is successful it will automatically commit for you. The semantics of "rollback" or "commit" are graph database dependent (i.e. some graphs may commit partial transactions even in the face of rollback) and in the case of JanusGraph will be further dependent upon the underlying storage engine (e.g. Cassandra, Hbase, etc).

Comment: Thank you! And to be sure: if I get traversal, then create 2 vertices using this traversal, and second creation fails, then both vertices will not be created in JanusGraph? I'm using JanusGraph with Cassandra backend

Comment: I don't think you should make that assumption with cassandra - it doesn't have strong acid guarantees. https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/transactions/

Comment: Can you recommend what to do if some operation of one JanusGraph traversal fails? I need to automatically recover after fail: start from last step which caused fail or undo all steps done before fail

Comment: one possible solution is to build your application so that all mutations are idempotent, then if you get a failure, you just retry the same traversal until it succeeds.